# Windows firewall ipv6 loopback issue

Tags: windows, ipv6, windows-firewall, loopback

I received it on my windows firewall log:
DROP TCP ::1 ::1 53264 47001

I tried to add ipv6 ::1 or any other ipv6 loopback address to the firewall rule but received only the message below:
An unspecified, multicast, broadcast and loopback IPv6 address was specified windows firewall.

I found some same question in https://github.com/falahati/WindowsFirewallHelper/issues/8
Where was indicated that : "This is a Windows Firewall limitation. You can not specify any loopback, broadcast or multicast IPv6 address."

What should I do?

Comment: Link to the photo which indicated the error message:
https://d.radikal.ru/d19/2108/e1/0fb9150bd1de.png

Comment: Dropping localhost traffic is a great way to break your computer's services. Don't even make the attempt.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the information about it, but how I may add to the exceptions ipv6 loopback IP address to the windows firewall rule?

p.s. It is on my VM

Comment: That's very strange because nothing should be blocking ::1 anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have a windows firewall rule which configured as: allow only 64000-65535. The DROP occurs on 47001 which is not included in the rule above. I create a custom rule configured as: allow IP any/any remote port 47001 and I didn't receive any DROP on windows FW. But I want to allow only IPv6 loopback address for this port and rule.Because request comes from ::1 which is IPv6 loopback address.

P.S. the DROP coming from 127.0.0.1 and ::1.

Comment: @MichaelHampton above comment wrong. I checked again. I still receive DROP on firewall log. Only when IP any/any and port any/any I don't receive any drop.